# Loading unknown amount of childs to TreeNode

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, treenode

I'm getting data from an API where archives are stored for each user.
Each archive can have 1 to unlimited sub archives and each sub archive can have 1 to ulimited sub archives and so on.

How can I load every archive and their sub archives into a TreeNode without 400 loops.
I thought about recursion but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it.

VB Example:

```
Sub Main()
    For Each archive in Archives
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(AllChilds(archive))
    Next
End Sub

Function AllChilds(parent_archive As Archive)
    If parent_archive.Archives.Count > 0 Then
        For Each subArchive As Archive In parent_archive.Archives
            If subArchive.Archives.Count > 0 Then
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(subArchive.DisplayName)
                AllChilds(subArchive)
            Else
                Return subArchive
            End If
        Next subArchive
    Else
        Return parent_archive
    End If
End Function
```

C# example:

```
class SurroundingClass
{
    public void Main()
    {
        foreach (archive as Archive in archives.Archives)
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(AllChilds(archive));
    }

    private void AllChilds(Archive parent_archive)
    {
        if (parent_archive.Archives.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Archive subArchive in parent_archive.Archives)
            {
                if (subArchive.Archives.Count > 0)
                {
                    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(subArchive.DisplayName);
                    AllChilds(subArchive);
                }
                else
                    return subArchive;
            }
        }
        else
            return parent_archive;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have an `Archive` class that looks something like this:

```vb
Public Class Archive

    Public Property DisplayName As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Archives As List(Of Archive)

End Class
```

and that `Archives` in your code is a `List(Of Archive)` or something else that implements  `IEnumerable(Of Archive)`. Just like the nodes of a `TreeView`, that is an inherently recursive data structure. As such, recursion is probably the best way to traverse it and build the tree of nodes as you go, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub ArchivesToTreeNodes(archives As IEnumerable(Of Archive), nodes As IList)
    For Each archive In archives
        Dim node As New TreeNode(archive.DisplayName)

        ArchivesToTreeNodes(archive.Archives, node.Nodes)
        nodes.Add(node)
    Next
End Sub
```

Sample usage:

```vb
Dim nodes As New List(Of TreeNode)

ArchivesToTreeNodes(Archives, nodes)
TreeView1.Nodes.AddRange(nodes.ToArray())
```